# Как программно создавать id для элемента?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, owl-carousel

У меня есть цикл, который выводит слайды (библиотека owl-carousel2) с информацией по врачам. И для каждого слайда (класс doctors_slider__item) мне надо создать уникальный ID для элемента, чтобы потом можно было обратиться к нему по другой ссылке на этой же странице и открыть нужного доктора. Собственно, вот код:

```
<!-- Сам слайдер -->
    <div id="doctors_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme doctor_slider">
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'Specialists',
                    'post_per_page' => -1,
                    'order' => 'asc',
                );
                $specialists = new WP_Query( $args ); 

                if( $specialists->have_posts() ) {
                    while ($specialists->have_posts() ) {
                    $specialists->the_post(); ?>
             <!-- Определенный слайд, которому надо присвоить ID -->
                        <div class="doctors_slider__item" id="">

                        </div>
                    <?php } 
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                    }?>
                </div>
```

Comment: у вас же там jquery подключен по умолчанию ?

Comment: ну да, owl-carousel без него не работает вроде как

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jgMZNQ  вот смотри - вариант ? я ужас как упрастил

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю это вопрдпресс ? Каждый врач = отдельный пост в wp ?

Если да,  то попробуйте вот так вот:

```
<div class="doctors_slider__item" id="<?php get_the_ID() ?>">
```

Но я бы завязался не на id, а через планиг ACF добавил бы уникальное поле, и выводил бы его туда. Типа id="doctor_vasilii_petrovich"

Comment: Нет, мне надо немного не так. Все оказалось намного проще, нужно было создать переменную со счетчиком и прописать в самом id, что id="slide-<?php echo $counter; ?>". Чтобы id назывались: slide-1, slide-2 и т.д. По сути это сработало, но нужный слайд по ссылке у меня все равно не открывается) Хотел сделать что-то вот такое, но с модальным окном https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/urlhashnav.html#three